# Use windows 7 use Credential Manager for saving passwords (.NET 2.0)

Tags: c#, security, credentials, credential-providers, credential-manager

is it possible to access the Windows security class in .NET 2.0 (C#) and saving/reading data from it?
( Credential Manager )

I mean the "Credential Manager" where windows saving the Remotedesktop authentication data etc.

Or if not how i can save passwords secure? Like Encrypt data with user person informations or hardware id or something else which is unique.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You can use the `Credential Manager` using some `DllImport`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22435672/2996339

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Win32 API [`CredWrite`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375187(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`CredRead`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374804(v=vs.85).aspx).

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221245/how-do-i-store-and-retrieve-credentials-from-the-windows-vault-credential-manage) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410186/c-sharp-using-credwrite-to-access-c) answer.