# How can I add Windows Credentials to Credentials Manager on Windows programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-10, credentials, credential-manager

I have looked at this question's selected answer,
*[Retrieve Credentials from Windows Credentials Store using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741424/retrieve-credentials-from-windows-credentials-store-using-c-sharp)*, which uses the [CredentialManagement](http://nuget.org/packages/CredentialManagement/) [NuGet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet) package to get and set credentials on Windows.

> Credential Management package is a wrapper for the Windows Credential Management API that supports both the old and the new style of UI

I was able to set new credentials that way. However, they were set as **Generic Credentials**.

```
public static bool SetCredentials(
     string target, string username, string password, PersistanceType persistenceType)
    {
        return new Credential
        {
            Target = target,
            Username = username,
            Password = password,
            PersistanceType = persistenceType
        }.Save();
    }
```

According to [this](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/credential-manager-where-windows-stores-passwords-other-login-details), there are at least four different types of credentials that the Windows Credentials Manager can use:

- Windows Credentials
- Certificate-Based Credentials
- Generic Credentials
- Web Credentials

The credentials I need to set are intended to allow access to a specific local web server, and when I have added them manually as **Windows Credentials** they work, when they get added as **Generic Credentials** by the application, or myself, they don't work.

[image]

I couldn't find enough information about this [here](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=credentialmanagement), so how can I add Windows Credentials to the Windows Credentials Manager by using this package, or in any other way that can be done programmatically?

I managed to solve my issue by doing it the way it's shown in this question: *[C# Using CredWrite to Access C$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410186/c-sharp-using-credwrite-to-access-c)*.